# div container not centering

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with some basic css stuff I was browseing the net for this but found examples but none of that explained my problem:

**Page template [HTML]:**

```
    <div id="container" class="gallery-list"> <!-----gallery-list---->
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div id="gallery-list-container" class="list-container">
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 
                <?php
                // Set up the arguments for retrieving the pages
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_status' => null,
                // $post->ID gets the ID of the current page
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                    'order' => ASC,
                    'orderby' => title
                    );
                 $subpages = get_posts($args);
                  if ($subpages[0]) :?>
                        <div class="gallery-list-wrap">
                            <?php
                             // Just another WordPress Loop
                             foreach($subpages as $post) :
                                setup_postdata($post);
                            ?>
                                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="list-entry-container">
                                    <?php 
                                        $count++;
                                        // Show the Post thumbnail
                                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

                                                <div class="list-entry">
                                                    <a class="size-small" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
                                                    <h2 class="list-entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'highart' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                </div><!-- .entry-content -->                   
                                            <?php
                                        // Show the High Art image
                                         else : ?>
                                            <div class="entry-content">
                                                <?php highart_entry_image_attachment('thumbnail') ?>
                                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->                       
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <div class="entry-utility">
                                            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'highart' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                                        </div><!-- .entry-utility -->
                                </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                 <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

**[CSS]**

```
#main .gallery-list{margin:0;width:925px;overflow:hidden; display:block;}
#main .gallery-list #content{width:925px;}
.list-container{margin:0 auto; display:block; padding:11px 0 0; list-style:none; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}
.gallery-list #gallery-list-container {margin-top:-22px;float:none; width:925px;}
.gallery-list li {display:inline;width:185px;height:241px;margin-right:25px;padding:22px 0 44px;border:1px solid lightgray;border-width:0 0 0; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.gallery-list #gallery-list-container li {min-height:252px; display:inline;clear:none;padding-bottom:25px;}
.gallery-list-wrap{display:inline; float:left; margin:0 auto;}
.list-entry-container {display:inline; float:left;}
.gallery-list .list-entry{display:inline;width:165px;font-size: 9px; font-weight:400; line-height:11px; text-transform:uppercase; padding:5px 0 6px;}
.gallery-list-line-wrap{margin: 0 auto; display:block;}
```

why the div: gallery-list-wrap is not centering on the container?
It just stay's aligned to the left of the container.

In this case I don't really understand how the browser processes this.

Probably a newbie question but I just can't seem to figure it out

**EDIT1:**
According to the answers below this could be a problematic approach on this so some backstory:
I have a div that is containing div's of subpages with thumbnails and titles of a page. so far so good the problem is I don't know how manny there are so I don't know if I have 1,2,3 or 4 per line I would like to have maximum 4 per line and each line centered to the container

is this eaven doable?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It is preferred you dont link to things but post your actual problem - or a representation that does demo its behavior so that people can reference and understand when they find your post in the future.

Comment: One part of solving a problem is understanding it. That is a subjective process, we try to help here, too, but you need to actually ask a specific question that is of use for others, too. Not only for yourself. This is not a "how to make me my website" forum here but a Programming Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove

```
display:inline;
float:left;
```

and add a width to the gallery-list-wrap.

At the moment you have margin-left and margin-right set to auto which is the correct thing to do, however for it to work properly you need to define a width as well.

So if you are having two div's in there, work out their combined width and apply that to the gallery-list-wrap.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help worked partially view: EDIT1

Comment: As for edit1:add to your gallery-list-wrap width:925px; text-align:center; then make the list-entry-container display:inline-block; and remove their float left

Comment: Your are a genious sir Thank you and +1 ofc

Answer (score 1):

delete:

```
display: inline;
float: left;
```

Comment: Thanks for help worked partially view: EDIT1